# Building A signed Apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an android project with Android Studio. To publish it on Play Store, I want to generate signed apk. When i start to make a signed apk it says build:failed and

File 'C:\Users\buzka\AndroidStudioProjects\Kasifeyoklama\app\Users\buzka\AndroidStudioProjects\Kasifeyoklama\kasifeyoklama2.jks' specified for property 'signingConfig.signingConfigData.storeFile' does not exist.

Is there anything for me to solve this error?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a key store path first. Click the "Create new..." button under the field where you entered C:\Users\buzka\AndroidStudioProjects\Kasifeyoklama\app\Users\buzka\AndroidStudioProjects\Kasifeyoklama\kasifeyoklama2.jks

Comment: Can you please explain more detailed? I have created key store path by clicking "Create new" button

Comment: Once you've created a key store you shouldn't be seeing a "does not exist" error.

Also, please double check your keystore path. It looks like half of the path is entered twice (Users\buzka\AndroidStudioProjects\Kasifeyoklama)

Try C:\Users\buzka\AndroidStudioProjects\Kasifeyoklama\kasifeyoklama2.jks